# Trunc functiong example in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I came across the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
CASE 
  WHEN WEEK >= TO_CHAR(TRUNC(to_date('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD')-7,'D')+4,'IYYY-IW') 
   THEN TRUNC(DISCONNECT_DATE_DATETIME)
  ELSE TRUNC(DISCONNECT_DATE_DATETIME,'D') END AS DAY
from some_Table
```

Could someone please explain me the usage of "trunc" function in the above query, as I'm not able to understand it.

Thanks

Comment: RTFM - [link1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions200.htm), [link2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm)

Comment: @GurV is correct. Specifically, check out [the page these link to](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions230.htm#i1002084) which outlines the `fmt` parameter usages. Here, 'D' will move the date to the start of the week. Which day of week that will be depends on your database configuration.

Comment: @HepC what I'm unable to understand is what is the -7 and +4 doing to the query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff My question is what is the -7 and +4 doing to the query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff `TRUNC( value )` and `TRUNC( value, 'D' )` are not the same - the first is the same as `TRUNC( value, 'DD' )` and will truncate to midnight of the same day whereas the second will truncate to midnight of the first day of the week (depending on the `NLS_TERRITORY` session parameter).

Answer (score 1):

1. `to_date('{RUN_DATE_YYYYMMDD}','YYYYMMDD')` converts your string to a `DATE` data type.
2. `date_value - 7` subtracts 7 days from the date.
3. `TRUNC( date_value, 'D' )` truncates the date value to midnight on the first day of the week (as determined by the `NLS_TERRITORY` session parameter).
4. `date_value + 4` adds 4 days to the date.
5. `TO_CHAR( date_value, 'IYYY-IW' )` converts the date to the: 4-digit year based on the ISO standard; followed by the Week of year (1-52 or 1-53) based on the ISO standard.

Looking at the effect of `NLS_TERRITORY`:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'America';

SELECT dt,
       TO_CHAR(TRUNC(dt-7,'D')+4,'IYYY-IW') as dt1,
       TO_CHAR(dt-7,'IYYY-IW') AS dt2
FROM   ( SELECT (SYSDATE + LEVEL - 1) AS dt FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7 );

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'France';

SELECT dt,
       TO_CHAR(TRUNC(dt-7,'D')+4,'IYYY-IW') AS dt1,
       TO_CHAR(dt-7,'IYYY-IW') AS dt2
FROM   ( SELECT (SYSDATE + LEVEL - 1) AS dt FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7 );
```

Outputs:

```
Session altered.


DT        DT1     DT2   
--------- ------- -------
05-APR-17 2017-13 2017-13
06-APR-17 2017-13 2017-13
07-APR-17 2017-13 2017-13
08-APR-17 2017-13 2017-13
09-APR-17 2017-14 2017-13
10-APR-17 2017-14 2017-14
11-APR-17 2017-14 2017-14

 7 rows selected 


Session altered.


DT       DT1     DT2   
-------- ------- -------
05/04/17 2017-13 2017-13
06/04/17 2017-13 2017-13
07/04/17 2017-13 2017-13
08/04/17 2017-13 2017-13
09/04/17 2017-13 2017-13
10/04/17 2017-14 2017-14
11/04/17 2017-14 2017-14

 7 rows selected
```

You can see that your query gives a different result when run on a Sundays (i.e. 09-Apr-2017) when the `NLS_TERRITORY` setting changes from `America` (where the first day of the week is Sunday) to `France` (where the first day of the week is Monday).

If you are in a territory where the first day of the week is Monday then you can simplify your query to:

```
TO_CHAR(dt-7,'IYYY-IW')
```

Comment: But why is dt1 when dt is 5-apr or 6-apr giving 2017-13, because the current week going on is week 13, however dt1 should be 5th april -7 days which is 29th march (first day of that week is 26th march), now adding 4 days to 26th march becomes 30th march and that is week 12?

Comment: @Arman ISO week 1 starts on 2017-01-02 this year (being the Monday of the week containing 2017-01-04), week 13 starts on 2017-03-27 and week 14 on 2017-04-03.